# How to see results via `mlflow ui` for experiments logged on a other server?

Tags: python, mlflow, mlops

I was running ML experiments on a ssh server, the experiments were logged via mlflow and stored in local `mlruns` on the server.

The code were just basic usage of mlflow and looks like this

```py
import numpy as np
import mlflow
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from pathlib import Path
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Path('./plot').mkdir(exist_ok = True)
    mlflow.set_experiment('demo-exp')
    with mlflow.start_run():
        x     = np.random.randn(10, 1)
        y     = np.random.randn(10, 1)
        model = LinearRegression().fit(x, y)
        py    = model.predict(x)
        r2    = r2_score(y, py)
        plt.plot(y, py, '+')
        plt.savefig('./plot/result.png')
        plt.close()

        mlflow.log_metric('r2', r2)
        mlflow.log_artifact('./plot/result.png')
```

Now I want to see the logged metrics and artifactos from my own laptop, so I tried

```
mlflow ui \
    --default-artifact-root=sftp:///USER_NAME@ADDRESS/path/to/experiment/mlruns \
    --port=8888 \
```

However, it looks like nothing showed in `localhost:8888` on my own laptop.

Anything I did wrong about the code and `mlflow ui` command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Run mlflow on a remote server

```
mlflow server --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8888
```

- Configure ssh local port forward on your local machine, like this:
  [SSH Port forwarding in a ~/.ssh/config file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9146457/ssh-port-forwarding-in-a-ssh-config-file)

```
LocalForward 8888 your_remote_machine_addr:8888
```

- Connect to localhost:8888 on your browser